# Java Package doesnt not exist in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I am new to Java and i have to execute a code snippet related to Kafka which is given below:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;

public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        String topicName = "SimpleProducerTopic";
        String key = "Key1";
        String value = "Value-1";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <>(props);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
        producer.send(record);
        producer.close();

        System.out.println("SimpleProducer Completed.");
    }

}
```

I have downloaded IntelliJ Idea editor and running the above script there but it is giving me an error

> Error:(2, 1) java: package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not
>   exist

I know that i apache kafka is missing so i downloaded a jar file of apache and add it to modules but the error still persist. What should i do? How do install the pacakge?

Comment: Try use maven for dependency managment...

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding the jar to the corresponding module does not give you access to it. Have you tried right click on the jar Add as Library... option?

Edit: you could perhaps explore other options for external library usage like maven, or gradle.

Comment: There is no such option (add as library) which i clicked on kafka jar file which is inside the External libraries.

Comment: I meant through IntelliJ UI. Right click on the jar in your IntelliJ working tree

Answer (score 0):

One way to install the package is to use Maven. If you want to configure Maven and IntelliJ, take a look at [this tutorial](https://javacord.org/wiki/getting-started/intellij-maven/). Eventually, once you are done, you should add [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.1.0) to the auto-generated `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Whatever you put during setup</groupId>
    <artifactId>Whatever you put during setup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    //Add this - copy and paste
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

You can add any additional packages/dependencies within the `<dependencies></dependencies>` tags. There are plenty of tutorials online on how to handle dependencies using Maven.

Comment: I have add pom.xml but no progress.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan can you update your question with what you have done

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan just to make sure, have you setup your Maven project properly? Just having a pom.xml file is not enough, here is an example of how to setup a Maven project in IntelliJ https://javacord.org/wiki/getting-started/intellij-maven/

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan just tried and it worked for me, let me update the answer really quickly for you.

Comment: Well i have follow the tutorial completely but still the same error even tutorail import are not working Error:(3, 24) java: package org.javacord.api does not exist

Comment: Don't use that dependency, use what you need - the pom.xml I gave you and your original code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188345/discussion-between-vs97-and-muhammad-faizan-khan).

Answer (score 0):

As being new to Java, you'll want to understand what is the classpath.

Putting JARs directly into your IDE isn't changing that

Even from the command line, you'd need to explicitly specify `-cp kafka-clients.jar`

There's multiple ways to modify the module classpath in Intellij, but manually downloading JARs should be avoided, and that problem is solved by dependency management tools such as Maven or Gradle (or sbt, etc)

Your profile mentions other languages, so think Nuget, npm, pip, etc. Apply that knowledge to Java